# Can I get CMake to use MS Visual C++ properly on Cygwin?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, command-line-interface, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 10; but I've recently installed the MSVC 2019 compiler.

I can, of course, write `CXX=/path/to/cl.exe` (or `CC=/path/to/cl.exe` if I ignore how MSVC isn't a proper C compiler), but if I try configuring a C or C++ project that way, I get something like:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30133.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/joeuser/src/myproj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_1b995/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/joeuser/src/myproj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe"    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/joeuser/src/myproj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/home/joeuser/src/myproj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx'
    cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_1b995.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/joeuser/src/myproj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_1b995/fast] Error 2
```

So, CMake is trying to pass GCC-like command-line options to MSVC. Can I get it to "play nice" and actually be able to use MSVC properly?

Comment: No. I tried this with Xcode and Visual C++. Each toolchain substantially different options.

Comment: Why are you trying to use cygwin and visual studio? Why not just use native Windows where this will just work?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: 1. I'm not trying to use Visual Studio, just MSVC. 2. Native Windows doesn't have CMake, for example.

Comment: @moi: But I know CMake supports MSVC _somehow_...

Comment: Native Windows does have CMake. Even Visual Studio bundles a copy of one. See here: https://cmake.org/download/

Comment: @rustyx: 1. You can download CMake for Windows, but CMake is not part of Windows. 2. "Even Visual Studio" - even the 8 GB behemoth I don't need, you mean? I already have CMake as part of Cygwin. I just want to use it with MSVC.

Comment: "CMake is not part of Windows" erm, neither is visual studio or cygwin? If you really must use cygwin use a compiler that is supported on that platform (i.e. the version of gcc provided by cygwin)